# sed/awk specify ranges in regex

Tags: regex, bash, sed, range

I have a file list output like this:

```
/path/F201405151800
/path/F201405151900
/path/F201405152000
/path/F201405152100
```

I piped this output to sed and used the following syntax:

```
sed -n '/F.\{8\}'$var1'/,/F.\{8\}'$var2'/p'
```

$var1 and $var2 are user inputs and as it can be seen, they refer to hours of the day in my files list. The above syntax works perfectly if $var1 and $var2 values are found. But if the value of $var1 is 16, and $var2 is 19 sed will not output anything because 16 will not be found in the above file list range.

A solution to this was:

```
sed -n '/F.\{8\}1[6-9]/p'
```

...which works but the issue I am facing now is how to specify double digit ranges in order to include something like: 16-20. I tried globbing between single quotes (like I'm doing with variables) like this:

```
sed -n '/F.\{8\}'{16..21}'/p'
```

...but the output I get is:

```
sed: can't read /F.\{8\}16/p: No such file or directory
sed: can't read /F.\{8\}17/p: No such file or directory
sed: can't read /F.\{8\}18/p: No such file or directory
sed: can't read /F.\{8\}19/p: No such file or directory
sed: can't read /F.\{8\}20/p: No such file or directory
sed: can't read /F.\{8\}21/p: No such file or directory
```

I don't really need to use sed, I explored some options with awk but could not obtain what I want, the main issue being that I can't figure out how to specify a regex RS so that I have the hours block as an awk field and do some conditions like

```
'$2 > 16 && $2 < 21 {print}'
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to add `-e`:

```
sed -n -e '/F.\{8\}'"$var1"'/,/F.\{8\}'"$var2"'/p'
```

And always quote the variables to prevent word splitting.

Update:

```
awk -v A=17 -v B=21 -F/ '!/\/F[0-9]{12}$/{next} {h = substr($NF, 10, 2)} h >= A && h <= B'
```

Comment: Doesn't work. I even tried with specific values instead of variables. If one of the values is not found, sed will not print anything.

Comment: What happened when you tried with specific values instead of variables, did it print anything?

Comment: It didn't print anything.

Comment: `sed -n -e '/F.\{8\}1800/,/F.\{8\}2100/p' file` prints the four lines for me. You sure your input for `var1` and `var2` is done correctly? You can debug your command by placing echo on top of it: `echo sed -n -e '/F.\{8\}'"$var1"'/,/F.\{8\}'"$var2"'/p'<new line><actual command>`

Comment: Please review my question and my first comment. It already worked for me when the values I specify exist. But when I input a value lower than 18, sed will not print anything.

Comment: I think other people already gave an idea about how you could do it. I also added mine. Please see update.

Comment: I see. How did the `awk` command didn't work? Any error you saw or unexpected output? Perhaps you can try upgrading to a [newer version of awk (gawk)](http://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/). Something like 4.x.x.

Comment: created "sedrange" file and put the four example lines in it. Then I did cat sedrange | (your sed/awk syntaxes). There is no error, nothing is printed. I will try upgrading to 4.x.x

Comment: Oh yes of course you have to give input to awk. My command didn't present an argument for the file thinking that you're the one that would give it. `awk ... your_file`. Similarly in sed: `sed ... your_file`

Answer (score 0):

You can use this awk:

```
awk -F'/' '{h=$3; gsub(/^F[0-9]{6}|[0-9]{4}$/, "", h)} h > 12 && h < 21' file
/path/F201405151800
/path/F201405151900
/path/F201405152000
/path/F201405152100
```

Comment: This syntax does not display anything for me. GNU Awk 3.1.8

Answer (score 0):

In order to have double digit ranges you can try something like this:

```
sed -n '/F.\{8\}(1[6-9]|2[01])/p'
```

Comment: Doesn't print anything.